# getting the value/key from a dynamic map object in immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a dynamic immutable object and I want to know a better way to get a deep-level value. [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/lau_chung/hf7Lsusr/12/)

```
var map = {aaa:{bbb:{ccc:'ddd'}}}
map = Immutable.fromJS(map)
```

Suppose that I don't know the third-level key `ccc`, what is the best way to get its value, which in this case `ddd`?

```
var map = {aaa:{bbb:{ccc:'ddd'}}}
map = Immutable.fromJS(map)

map.keySeq().toList().map(first=>{
    map.get(first).keySeq().toList().map(second=>{
      map.getIn([first,second]).valueSeq().toList().map(third=>{
           alert(third)
      })
  })
})
```

Is the above example an appropriate way to get the value `ddd`. I can't simply use `map.getIn(['aaa','bbb','ccc'])` because this map object is dynamic in my situation

Comment: You could still use `map.getIn(['aaa','bbb'])` and iterate just over that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you're trying to obtain the key which has `ddd` value. If you're aware of the object nesting levels, you can simply flatten it.

```
var map = {aaa:{bbb:{ccc:'ddd'},eee:{fff:'ggg'}}};
var map = map.flatten(3);
/// {
///  ccc: "ddd",
///  fff: "ggg"
/// }
```

Now, simply filter the map and obtain requisite key.